# jquery selector for links with href=# + variable

Tags: jquery

I wonder if its possible to use a variable within a jquery selector like $("a [href=# . . .]). I tried:

```
var activeTab = 'tabs-4';
var expr = "\"" + "a[href=\\\\#" + activeTab + "]\"";
$(expr).click();

Result: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "a[href=\\#tabs-4]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your quotation mark nesting and remove the useless escape sequences:

```js
var activeTab = 'tabs-4';
var expr = "a[href='#" + activeTab + "']";
$(expr).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#tabs-4" onclick="alert('clicked')">tabs-4</a>
```

Or save yourself the hassle and use template literals (not supported in IE 11):

```js
var activeTab = 'tabs-4';
var expr = `a[href='#${activeTab}']`;
$(expr).click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#tabs-4" onclick="alert('clicked')">tabs-4</a>
```